# Dynamically modify JS Object's behavior

Tags: javascript, properties

is it possible to decide at runtime which properties of a JS object should be enumerated?

Something like

```
myobj = {};
myobj.keys = function() {  // I made this keys function up. Is there something like that in JS?
  if ((new Date).getSeconds() < 30)
    return [1,2,3];
  else
    return [4,5,6];
}

for(p in myobj)
  console.log(p); // returns either 1,2,3 or 4,5,6
```

Furthermore, is it possible to call a function if a object's property does not exist?
Something like

```
myobj.fallbackFunction = function(arg) { return arg; };
console.log( myobj['nonexisting-property'] ); // returns the string 'nonexisting-property'
```

And my final question:
Is it possible to call an object as a function?
Like

```
myobj.call = function(arg) { console.log(arg) };
myobj(123)  // returns 123`
```

Sorry, I've had a look at Qt's QScriptEngine where you can do stuff like that, but I don't know how to implement this in native JS...

Cheers,
Manuel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to control which properties of an object are enumerated using [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) in ECMAScript 5, [which is currently making its way into browsers](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/):

```
var o = { "foo": 1, "bar": 2 };

for (var i in o) { console.log(i); } // Logs "foo" and "bar";

Object.defineProperty(o, "foo", { enumerable: false });

for (var i in o) { console.log(i); } // Logs just "bar";
```

For the next part, there's no standardized or cross-browser way to call a method if a property of an object is undefined.

Finally, you can't make any old object callable as a function, but you could just define your variable as a function in the first place and it will have all the usual features of an object, since functions are themselves objects (`Function.prototype` inherits from `Object.prototype`). For example, you can assign properties to functions:

```
var f = function() { alert("Hello"); };
f.myProp = 1;
```